# Migrar en Wordpress desde WPBakery Page Builder a Gutenberg

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Tengo una web desarrollada en WordPress con el plugin WPBakery Page Builder. Quiero migrar todas las entradas y páginas creadas con el plugin a Gutenberg. ¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?. Gracias.

Comment: Has probado a seguir los pasos en este link? https://ulement.com/tutorial/convert-wpbakery-to-gutenberg/

Comment: Lo he probado. Me funciona. Muchas gracias. Aunque creo que deberé toar las entradas una auna a mano, porque algunas imágenes de las publicaciones han desaparecido

Comment: Genial, me alegro!!!